# Print large SVG chart on separate pages

Tags: printing, svg

I am trying to print a large SVG chart from a browser, the SVG chart is embedded into the HTML.  The width / height of the chart is set to absolute.  The print only prints a part of the SVG chart, however much will fit on 1 page, and cuts the rest off.  Is there a way to split up the chart to print into separate pages?

Answer (score 0):

This totally depends on what browser you are using to view the SVG.  Either try a different browser...  Safari has GREAT printing capabilities (on the Mac at least)..  or... "isolate" the SVG..  Either look at the source and figure out the relative URL to the embedded SVG and enter it into the URL bar..

```
<td><object id="object" type="image/svg+xml" data="**smiley.svg**">Please use a modern browser!</object></td>
<td><iframe id="iframe" src="**smiley.svg**">Please use a modern browser!</iframe></td>
<td><embed id="embed" src="**smiley.svg**" type="image/svg+xml" /></td>
<td><img id="img" alt="smiley face" src="**smiley.svg**" /></td>
```

or Copy and paste the actual SVG code from the inline source and paste it into a plain text document with the .svg extension...

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:-1;">
<linearGradient id="gradient">
<stop class="begin" offset="0%"/>
<stop class="end" offset="100%"/>
</linearGradient>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" style="fill:url(#gradient)" />
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="30" style="fill:url(#gradient)" />
</svg>
```

Then you can use a multitude of applications, from Illustrator, to the free [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/), or MANY, many others to manipulate (or print) it to your hearts content.

Comment: Anything I can do to change the SVG code to make it print on separate pages for IE7?

Comment: Yes, the instructions I gave you are universal.  "View Source" from the page.. and you will see, SVG's are nothing more than a string of words, beginning and ending with `<svg>...</svg>`  If you are unwilling to extract them and print with a less crappy piece of software, I'm sure there are many different ways to "print" from IE7, either through Free or adobe PDF plugins, Microsoft XPS, or whatever it's called, or simply take a screen shot, and print that!!  But whatever you do, don't forget to mark my answer as the solution.  THAT is what is really important, lol.  J/k.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  Last question, what changes will I need to make to the SVG code to break up the chart for printing?  Can I just add the normal HTML onBeforePrint tag and call it in JS to add a pagebreak?  Or is there some unique svg code that will break it up on print?

Answer (score 0):

Use phantomjs.org project to generate your chart images at server. 
It allows to load any HTML page by URL into headless WebKit machine and render it into PNG.
Plus, you can get final size of your page and then cut it into peaces via defining Clip Region in cycle.

For example next sample exports several charts from the page into separate PNG images in file system. After that you can assemble your new web page or pack them into PDF and provide download link to your user. This would be the most reliable and stable printing solution for web application.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 1280, height : 1024 };
page.open('http://chart.html', function () {
    page.clipRect = page.evaluate(function () {
        var chart = jQuery("#chart1");
        return { top: chart.offset().top, left: chart.offset().left, width: chart.outerWidth(), height: chart.outerHeight() };  
    });
    page.render('chart1.png');
    page.clipRect = page.evaluate(function () {
        var chart = jQuery("#chart2");
        return { top: chart.offset().top, left: chart.offset().left, width: chart.outerWidth(), height: chart.outerHeight() };  
    });
    page.render('chart2.png');    
    page.clipRect = page.evaluate(function () {
        var chart = jQuery("#chart3");
        return { top: chart.offset().top, left: chart.offset().left, width: chart.outerWidth(), height: chart.outerHeight() };  
    });
    page.render('chart3.png');        
    phantom.exit();
});
```